# Login functionality in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a login functionality.  I am using core data to achieve this and am able to register a new user successfully. The details such as username and password are stored in the entity. I now want to compare these values with the user input in the login detail page.

Here is the code for the signup.

```
//first we grab the managed obj context
        managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        //creating an instance
        //getting the entity in which the data is to be stored and store the new obj with the data in it
        NSManagedObject *pplAcc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        //populating the obj with the data stored in the text fields
        [pplAcc setValue:nameTxt.text forKey:@"name"];
        [pplAcc setValue:paswordTxt.text forKey:@"password"];
        [pplAcc setValue:radioLbl forKey:@"radio"];

        //saving the img in binary format
        NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profImg.image);
        [pplAcc setValue:imgData forKey:@"image"];

        //saving
        NSError *error;
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error in saving %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"User registration successful");
            LoginViewController *lvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES]; 
        }
```

Here is the code for the login.

```
-(IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender{

    managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    //fetching the result
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Person"];


NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",nameTxt.text];
    NSPredicate *passwordPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"password = %@", passwordTxt.text];
    NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[namePredicate, passwordPredicate]];

    [fetch setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    //excuting the fetch result
    NSArray *arrayFetch = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    //checking to see if the user input equals the fetched managedobj in coredata
    if (
        [nameTxt.text isEqual:[arrayFetch valueForKey:@"name"]] &&
        [passwordTxt.text isEqual:[arrayFetch valueForKeyPath:@"password"]] &&
        [radioLbl isEqual:[arrayFetch valueForKey:@"radio"]]
        ) {
        if ([radioLbl isEqual: @"Student"]) {
            StudentViewController *student = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"student"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:student animated:YES];
        }
        else if ([radioLbl isEqual: @"Instructor"]){
            InstructorViewController *instructor = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"instructor"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:instructor animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Incorrect username/password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [error show];
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the alert view of "Incorrect username/password" whenever I try to login.

Comment: Ameen, make sure you are having no space in your textfield , in my case it did some error due to autmatically adding extra space in textfield (Intellisence )

Comment: secondly log first the value of your arrayFetch, and then log the Predicate's value. This will make you clear., what's going behind the scene

Comment: I did the NSLog but the value is empty.....it is not display null, it is just not displaying anything at all. By looking at the code do you know what the problem is?

Comment: arrayFetch is display empty brackets and the predicate is displaying the value currently entered in the text field

Comment: add some value to it then in your arrayFetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem and I am posting the updated code here for anyone else who needs help. The changes are made in the login code.

```
  -(IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender{


    managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    //fetching the result
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Person"];


    NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",nameTxt.text];
    NSPredicate *passwordPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"password = %@", passwordTxt.text];
    NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[namePredicate, passwordPredicate]];

    [fetch setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

    NSManagedObject *object = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    //excuting the fetch result
    NSArray *arrayFetch = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

if ([arrayFetch count] > 0) {

        object = [arrayFetch objectAtIndex:0];
        //checking to see if the user input equals the fetched managedobj in coredata
        if ([nameTxt.text isEqualToString:[object valueForKey:@"name"]] || [passwordTxt.text isEqualToString:[object valueForKey:@"password"]]){
            if ([radioLbl isEqualToString:@"Student"]) {

                StudentViewController *student = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"student"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:student animated:YES];
            }
            else{
                InstructorViewController *instructor = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"instructor"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:instructor animated:YES];
            }

            nameTxt.text = @"";
            passwordTxt.text = @"";

        }
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Incorrect username/password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [error show];
    }
}
```

What I was missing in the above code was NSManagedObject. Basic mistake!

Answer (score 0):

How many objects are in arrayFetch ? Your're making a request in CoreData for all Person entries so you have all of them. I suggest to you to make a request with a predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicatewithformat:"name = %@",nameTxt.text];
```

If you get any result, then check the password with That person.

Comment: I have updated my answer using NSpredicate as you suggested but it is still showing "Incorrect username/password". I have also added the user registration code as well. But for login only name and password is required